# Executing GROUP BY clause with Aggregate Function inside FOR LOOP in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an `EMPLOYEE` table with some columns. I'm interested about three columns - `ENTRY_TIME (NUMBER)`, `EXIT_TIME (NUMBER)`, `NAME (VARCHAR2)`. The `NAME` column has no distinct entries, i.e., a value may appear multiple times.

I have taken few distinct `NAME` values and I want to get the maximum `EXIT_TIME` and the minimum `ENTRY_TIME` for each of these selected `NAME` values from the entire data.

I have written the following PL/SQL block:

```
DECLARE
  type namearray IS VARRAY(6) OF VARCHAR2(50);
  name namearray;
  total INTEGER;
  EntryTime NUMBER;
  ExitTime NUMBER;
  employeeNames VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  name := namearray('Peter','Job','George','Hans','Marco','Alison');
  total := name.count;
  FOR i in 1 .. total LOOP
    SELECT min(ENTRY_TIME), max(EXIT_TIME), NAME 
    INTO   EntryTime,       ExitTime,       employeeNames  
    from EMPLOYEE 
    GROUP BY NAME having NAME = name(i);
    dbms_output.put_line('EntryTime: ' || EntryTime || 'ExitTime: ' || ExitTime || 'Name: ' || employeeNames);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

It is providing following error:

```
    Error report -
    ORA-01403: no data found.
    ORA-06512: in line 12
    01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
    *Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
    *Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.
```

But data is there. I think there is something wrong with the query or the block itself.

Can someoneone help/suggest.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have updated

Comment: Hmmm. `GROUP BY NAME having NAME = name(i)` looks odd. Normally we would check an aggregated value in the HAVING clause. What happens if you try `WHERE NAME = name(i) GROUP BY NAME`?

Comment: It is providing the same error.

Comment: I don't know that it's causing you a problem but it is a bad idea to have a local variable `name`, `Entry_Time`, and `Exit_Time` with the same name as the columns of the table you are referencing.  Conventionally, you'd use a prefix for the local variable names (i.e. `l_name`).  What is the data type of `name` in the table?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I was also confused with the `HAVING CLAUSE` as @APC commented but I believe the problem is with the employee names you passed as there could be names which are not available in the `employee` table which leads to `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception and you need to handle such scenarios with `exception` and other than that even though its working I would suggest to change the `having clause` to `where clause`

Try below,

```
DECLARE
    type namearray IS VARRAY(6) OF VARCHAR2(50);
    name namearray;
    total INTEGER;
    EntryTime NUMBER;
    ExitTime NUMBER;
    employeeNames VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    name :=namearray('Peter','Job','George','Hans','Marco','Alison');
    total := name.count;
    FOR i in 1 .. total 
    LOOP
      BEGIN
        SELECT min(1), max(1), NAME 
          INTO EntryTime, ExitTime, employeeNames 
          FROM EMPLOYEE 
        GROUP BY NAME 
        HAVING NAME = name(i);
        dbms_output.put_line('EntryTime: ' || EntryTime || 'ExitTime: ' || ExitTime || 'Name: ' || employeeNames);
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         dbms_output.put_line('No data found for Name: ' || name(i));
      END;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*Consider the suggestion to have `WHERE` clause.:)*

Why I am saying this is what you can find in the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1c7e9757601fcf0bb3507a969ed8049b)

Answer (score 0):

Another option to exception handling is to outer join the selected employee names with the table. This is accomplished by creating a collection (array) at the schema level, then using the TABLE function on that a variable of that collection type. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c4ad8fa6400c21259c092cb01a93156b).

```
create type names_att is table of varchar2(50);

declare
    name names_att := names_att('Peter','Job','George','Hans','Marco','Alison');
begin
    for rec in 
        ( select min(entrytime)  entrytime
               , max(exittime)   exittime
               , na.column_value employeenames
           from table (name) na 
           left join employee  emp  on emp.employeenames = na.column_value
          group by na.column_value 
          order by na.column_value 
        )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('Name: ' ||rec.employeenames) ||
                             '  EntryTime: ' || nvl(to_char(rec.entrytime), '---') || 
                             '  ExitTime: '  || nvl(to_char(rec.exittime), '---')
                             ); 
                            
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Note: I defined an Associative Array rather than a Varray for the names. I am not sure this technique works with varray. I have never seen any reason for a varray.